# How to run .bat file on unix server

Tags: unix

I am not able to run ".bat" file on Unix server

I have run following command to run that ".bat" file.

```
sh Run.bat
```

where Run.bat is ".bat" file.
It gives me following error

> Invalid file (Bad Magic Number): Exec format error

what could be the possible error.
Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.bat` file is a Batch file for `Microsoft Windows` & `DOS`. Don't think you can run it on `Unix` environment.

Comment: From `.bat` file, I am opening excel file automatically. Is there any other way I can open that excel file automatically in `Unix` environment.

Answer (score 1):

`.bat` file is a Batch file for `Microsoft Windows` & `DOS`. Don't think you can run it on Unix environment.

In comment, you mentioned you are actually trying to open `Excel file` in your `.bat` file.

I would recommend to install **[Open Office](https://www.openoffice.org/)** or **[Libre Office](https://www.libreoffice.org/)**, then open `Excel file` with that.